# Assynchronous Cancelation while operation is running

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, cancellationtokensource

I'm starting a few tests about asynchronous programing in .net and now i'm stuck at trying ti cancel a long operation using cancellationToken.

So I have the following code:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancelationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

My buttons to start the operations

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancelationToken.Cancel(true);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartOperation(cancelationToken.Token);
    }
```

And finally my operations

```
    private async void StartOperation(CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        await GetItensFromDatabase2(cancelToken);
    }

    public static Task<int> GetItensFromDatabase(CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        //cancelToken.Register( () => Console.WriteLine("Canceled") );
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() =>
        {
            int result = 0;

            cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            result = MyLongOperation();  // Simulates my operation -> I want to cancel while this operation is still running

            return result;

        }, cancelToken);
    }
```

So, how to cancel MyLongOperation() method ? Is it possible to do ?

Comment: Please use `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew` for `async` code; [I explain why on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: Task.Run doesn't exist in .net 4

Comment: In `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`, it is `TaskEx.Run`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to cancel in any point, the purpose of CancellationToken is to allow user to cancel the operation, when the long running operation expect that...

```
while(!finished)
{
     cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
     //Some not cancelable operations
}
```

Here is more common method of cancelable method

```
private static void LongRunning(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if(cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }
        //Not canceled, continue to work
    }
}
```

The idea is, that user requests cancellation, but only executor decides when to stop his work. Usually executor do cancellation after reaching some "safe-point"

It is not good experiance to `Abort` long running operations without asking oppinion, a lot of posts have been written about this.

Comment: What you saying is that i only can cancel the operations inside a loop ?
and if my current execution point is outside of if(cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) and the user wants to cancel, so the cancelation isn't allowed at this point right ?

Comment: You can run loop linear, some code, than if(cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested) return; than other code, than again check for cancel and ...

Answer (score 1):

Well for starters you would have an issue that if you have already run through the logic which says "cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested" and then you cancel. How will the "MyLongOperation" know that you have cancelled the task? :)

Cancelling a long running task usually takes in a CancellationToken as an argument so the code would look something like:

```
// Check if cancelled
// do work part 1
// Check if cancelled
// do work part 2
```

The granularity of the cancellable operations is upto the developer.

Comment: That's the aproach im afraid of. Thanks